# wso2 cep stored procedures in SQL Server 2016

Tags: wso2, wso2-cep

I am trying to run a stored procedure in WSO2 CEP with SQL Server 2016. Is this possible? I already looked through the documentation on this which is scarce. there is only one sample with connection to SQL Server.

Although, it looks like it is limited to selects, inserts and deletes.

I was not able to find any documentation on other driver functionality through CEP.

Also, I did find some information on other WSO2 Services, not wso2 CEP, which might allow me to run the stored procedures. If you have any information on that and who to plug CEP with those services It would help as well.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2CEP is a real time analytics product which provides few SQL operations with RDBMS publisher to publish events as mentioned in the documentation [1].

Only work around would be modifying existing query defined `output-event-adapters.xml` file located in `<CEP-Location>/repository/conf` direcory. Inside  the file locate `<adapterConfig type="rdbms">` element and you will find properties of SQL operations such as update into like below.

```
 <property key="updateTableRow">UPDATE $TABLE_NAME SET $COLUMN_VALUES WHERE $CONDITION</property>
```

You can change above like below to execute stored procedure

```
 <property key="updateTableRow">EXEC $TABLE_NAME $COLUMN_VALUES</property>
```

Then in RDBMS publisher you need to change execution.mode as update.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/RDBMS+Event+Publisher